# Configuring ASP.NET MVC 2 with Spring.NET and FluentNHibernate

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, orm, fluent-nhibernate, spring.net

I'm trying to configure ASP.NET MVC 2 RC and Spring .NET 1.3 to use FluentNHibernate.

I've managed to get FluentNHibernate running inside console application.

At moment ASP.NET MVC 2 RC and Spring .NET are working fine for me, but I'm having trouble configuring FluentHibernate.

Before asking this question I have Googled a lot, I have also looked through relevant questions on StackOverflow.

I know that there is this (http://www.bennymichielsen.be/post/2009/01/04/Using-Fluent-NHibernate-in-SpringNet.aspx) blog post and Spring .NET documentation ORM chapter (http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html)

Just like Benny's blog suggests I have created "FluentNHibernateLocalSessionFactoryObject" the contents of this class is same as in blog post.

My Spring configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
         xmlns:db="http://www.springframework.net/database"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.net http://www.springframework.net/xsd/spring-objects.xsd">


  <object id="MySessionFactory" type="Project.Core.NHinbernate.FluentNHibernateLocalSessionFactoryObject, Spring.Data.NHibernate20">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="FluentNHibernateMappingAssemblies">
      <list>
        <value>Project.Core.NHibernate</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="HibernateProperties">
      <dictionary>
        <entry key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
      </dictionary>
    </property>
  </object>

  <object id="HomeController" singleton="false" type="Project.UI.Controllers.HomeController">
    <property name="MySessionFactory" value="MySessionFactory" />
  </object>
</objects>
```

I think this configuration has a lot of things missing (connection string, correct SQL Server 2008 dialect and DB provider).

My goal is to simply inject SessionFactory into HomeController.

I would be very greatful if you could point out what should be changed in my configuration file.

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't worked with ASP.NET MVC you indeed need to add a DbProvider to your configuration file. The DbProvider will hold the connection string. So add this to your configuration file.

```
  <db:provider id="DbProvider" 
  provider="System.Data.SqlClient" 
  connectionString="Data Source=(local);Database=Spring;User ID=springqa;Password=springqa;Trusted_Connection=False"/>
```

In order to use the db:provider syntax you'll also need to add this to your application configuration file (web/app.config)

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
       <sectionGroup name="spring">
           <section name="parsers" type="Spring.Context.Support.NamespaceParsersSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
       </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
<spring>
    <parsers>
       <parser type="Spring.Data.Config.DatabaseNamespaceParser, Spring.Data" />
    </parsers>
</spring>
</configuration>
```

Here's the [relevant link](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/dbprovider.html) to Spring.NET's documentation

Also look in the comments of the blogpost of Benny, there's an updated code sample.

Comment: But Spring .NET's doc says

"These provider implementations do not take into account usage with NHibernate. NHibernate scopes a SessionFactory, where second level caching is managed, to each connection."

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you give me a link to that statement?